# How can I disable the Stripe payment request button until a form is complete?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I have Stripe's payment request button set up on the same page as a form. The form has validation on it. I need to be able to disable the payment request button until the form has been completed but I haven't been able to find a way to do this.

Payment request button set up:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<div id="payment-request-button">
  <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
</div>
<script>
var stripe = Stripe('KEY');
var paymentRequest = stripe.paymentRequest({
  country: 'US',
  currency: 'usd',
  total: {
    label: 'Demo total',
    amount: 1000,
  },
  requestPayerName: true,
  requestPayerEmail: true,
});

var elements = stripe.elements();
var prButton = elements.create('paymentRequestButton', {
  paymentRequest: paymentRequest,
});

// Check the availability of the Payment Request API first.
paymentRequest.canMakePayment().then(function(result) {
  if (result) {
     prButton.mount('#payment-request-button');
   } else {
     document.getElementById('payment-request-button').style.display = 
 'none';
   }
 });

 paymentRequest.on('token', function(ev) {
   // Send the token to your server to charge it!
   fetch('/charges', {
     method: 'POST',
     body: JSON.stringify({token: ev.token.id}),
     headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
      // Report to the browser that the payment was successful, prompting
      // it to close the browser payment interface.
      ev.complete('success');
    } else {
      // Report to the browser that the payment failed, prompting it to
      // re-show the payment interface, or show an error message and close
      // the payment interface.
      ev.complete('fail');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Depends on what exactly is inserted in the place of `<!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->` - if the button renders inside an iframe that loads its content from a different domain, then you have no access at all to it. You could only disable this button, if it was actually part of your own document.

Comment: Yep the button is generated inside an iframe.

Comment: Just don't call `prButton.mount` until you are ready to allow the user to checkout. So move that code to only run after you've successfully validated the rest of the input.

Comment: Problem is I want the button to be displayed so that if you click on it and the form is invalid it will alert you to this so I need the button to be shown regardless of the current state of the form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can perform form validation in an event handler for the `click` event of the payment request button.

## Example

```
prButton.on('click', function(event) {
  if (!myForm.reportValidity()) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
});
```

## [Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events/on_click)

> ### `element.on('click', handler)`
>
> Triggered when the `Element` is clicked. This event is only emitted from a `paymentRequestButton` Element.
>
> #### `handler`
>
> When called it will be passed an event object with the following properties:
>
> ##### `preventDefault`
>
> Calling this function synchronously prevents the browser's payment interface from being shown. This can be used to validate the form before the payment interface is shown.